# Integrating power transformed Gaussian

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am working on a real world problem, and I don't know how to verify that my solution is correct other than asking here.

I know that if I integrate the square of x multiplied with a Gaussian distribution:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \frac 1 {\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}}dx=\mu^2+\sigma^2$$

In my real world problem, I don't have a Gaussian distribution. Using a power transform I get a much more reasonable description of reality. In that case I define transformed variables $x_T = x^\lambda$, $\mu_T=\mu^\lambda$ and $\sigma_T= \frac \sigma \mu \frac {\mu^\lambda} \lambda$ and we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_T^{2/\lambda} \frac 1 {\sigma_T \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac {(x_T-\mu_T)^2} {2\sigma_T^2}}dx_T$$
This did not look like fun, until I realized that $x_T^{2/\lambda}=x_T^{-2+2/\lambda}x_T^2$, and I figured I could re-use my solution for the Gaussian and integrate by parts. Now, it has been a while since I used this technique, so I would like to confirm that I am doing this correctly:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2} x_T^2 \frac 1 {\sigma_T \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac {(x_T-\mu_T)^2} {2\sigma_T^2}}dx_T = x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2} (\mu_T^2+\sigma_T^2) - (\mu_T^2+\sigma_T^2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\frac 2 \lambda - 2)x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 3}dx_T $$ $$= x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2} (\mu_T^2+\sigma_T^2) - (\mu_T^2+\sigma_T^2)[x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2}]_{-\infty}^\infty$$
I am quite certain that this only gives a useful answer for $\lambda<0$ or $\lambda \ge 1$ since in those cases (I think) $[x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2}]_{-\infty}^\infty = 0$; otherwise I think I get infinity. If $\lambda = 1$, the power transform doesn't do anything and I get the original result back. So at least it's not obviously wrong.

So, here my questions:

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Is there a quicker/more streamlined way to solve this?
3. Should I conclude that if $\lambda$ is somewhere between 0 and 1, the solution is always infinity? (i.e., in my practical application, I should try to manipulate the experiments so that I avoid this if I want useful results?)
4. Any suggestions for reading materials about methods I could use to verify my solutions?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: two typos which I saw as a result of a comment, that makes me realize I have an error in my transformation already. I'll work on this and see where I end up.

Comment: When changing $x\rightarrow x_T^{1/\lambda}$, did you remember to include $dx = (x_T^{1/\lambda - 1}/\lambda) d x_T$?

Comment: The term $x_T^{\frac 2 \lambda - 2} (\mu_T^2+\sigma_T^2)$ cannot be there because $x_T$ is integrated "out". Integration by parts is $\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx=-\int_a^bf'(x)g(x)dx+[f(x)g(x)]_a^b$. You do have a formula for the definite integral $\int_a^bg'(x)dx$ (from the standard Gaussian applied to $x^2$). You seem to confuse this with having a closed form expression for the antiderivative $g(x)$.

Comment: @Kurt G., I can only agree to being confused. As mentioned, I am a bit rusty. Just to check that I understand your suggestion, and ensure that I will move in the correct direction this time: did I do $f(x)[g(x)]_a^b$ instead of $[f(x)g(x)]_a^b$?

Comment: Yes. Plus in $-\int_a^bf'(x)g(x)dx$ it looks like you thought you knew $g(x)$ being $\mu^2+\sigma^2$ and pulled that out of the integral. Cute but wrong :). BTW I believe that there is no simple solution to the problem. We know the integer moments of the Gaussian distribution and afaik this is where it ends. Numeric integration should always work.

Comment: Exactly what I did, and I figured that would then be just as wrong ;). And with these comments, my confidence has shrunk. 
Are there any other “long tail” distributions for which this would become easier?